# ICMP ping all hosts in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, time-limit-exceeded, networking

I'm creating my own little toolbox for pinging IP interfaces (for the test, only in localhost). In the future I'm thinking of piping the output to a text file. But I'd like to focus on improving the performance for now.

For now, scanning a class A IP range is pretty fast, but for a B range (65025 addresses) it's very long. Taking in excess of 5 minutes.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
import os


# Define a function for the thread
def pingBox( threadName, host):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 "+host) 
    print('response for pinging %s is %s' %(threadName, response))
    if response == 0:
        print ('%s : is up' %host)
    else:
        print ('%s : is down' %host)
# Create one thread by ping
def createThread(host):
    try:
        tlist = []
        tlist.append(
            threading.Thread(
                target=pingBox,
                kwargs={
                    "threadName": "Thread:{0}".format(host),
                    "host":host
                }
        ))

        for t in tlist:
            t.start()

        for t in tlist:
            t.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def rangeSelector(ipRange):
    if ipRange== 'A' or ipRange== 'a':
        for i in range (0,255):
            createThread('127.0.0.'+str(i))
    elif ipRange== 'B' or ipRange== 'b':
        for i in range (0,255):
            for j in range(0,255):
                createThread('127.0.'+str(i)+'.'+str(j))
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ipRange=input('Choose range A|B :')
    rangeSelector(ipRange)
```

Comment: You do know that address range `127.0.0.0/24` is assigned to _localhost_ addresses (which respond very fast to ping on normal machines), but the rest of `127.0.0.0/16` is not (and likely won't respond at all), don't you?

Comment: @Warok, honestly, I've found the optimized solution since yesterday. But looking at this situation that fell into "disrepute", I feel doubt that such an effort would be adequately assessed. Too much of "bad energy" here ...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, could you anyway post it please?
I just wanted some advices, how to create my threads faster, or to speed up my script.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If your solution differs much from mine, then I too would like to see your insight.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, Yes, I'll put my contribution soon (writing it now). Thanks for participation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### *Towards better design, functionality and performance*

Start with good names: that means following Python naming conventions and give a meaningful names to your identifiers/functions/classes:

`rangeSelector` ---> **`ping_network_range`**
`createThread` ---> **`start_threads`**
`pingBox` ---> **`check_host`**

As [@Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) already mentioned `range(256)` is the valid range for your case.

The former `createThread` function tried to create a single thread with `start` ing and `join` ing it at one step. But that undermines the benefit of using *threading* for parallelizing computations. The crucial mechanics is that **all** treads are initiated/started at once, then, we `join` them (awaiting for their finishing) at next separate phase.
On constructing a `threading.Thread` no need to pass custom thread name through `kwargs={"threadName": ...}` - the [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) constructor already accepts **`name`** argument for the *thread name* which is then accessed within *target* function via **`threading.current_thread().name`**.

The former `pingBox` function used [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) function (executes the command (a string) in a *subshell*) which is definitely **not** a good choice.
 
The more robust, powerful and flexible choice is [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

> The `subprocess` module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to
>   their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This
>   module intends to replace several older modules and functions:
>   `os.system`, `os.spawn*` 
>   ... 
>   The recommended approach to invoking
>   subprocesses is to use the `run()` function for all use cases it can
>   handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying `Popen` interface
>   can be used directly.

Some good, user-friendly description - on this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731082/3185459).

Furthermore, the **`ping`** command (OS network tool) can be speed up itself through adjusting specific options. The most significant ones in such context are:

- `-n` (No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic names for host addresses. Allows to disable DNS lookup to speed up queries)
- `-W <number>` (Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absence of any responses, otherwise ping waits for two RTTs)
- `-i interval` (Wait `interval` seconds between sending each packet. The default is to wait for one second between each packet normally, or not to wait in flood mode. Only super-user may set interval to values less than 0.2 seconds)

The difference would be more noticeable on sending more than one packet (`-c` option).
In your case I'd apply `-n` and `-q` options. With `-q` option allows to quite the output since we'll get the *returned code* which itself indicates whether a particular host is reachable across an IP network. `subprocess.run` allows to access the [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode) explicitly.

---

The 2 nested `for` loops within the former `rangeSelector` function is flexibly replaced with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) routine to compose an efficient generator expression yielding formatted IP addresses:

```
from itertools import product
...
start_threads(f'127.0.{i}.{j}' for i, j in product(range(256), range(256)))
```

---

***Designing command-line interface***

As your program is planned to be used as part of pipeline, instead of hanging on interactive, blocking call of `input('Choose range A|B :')` - the more flexible and powerful way is using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module that allows building an extended and flexible command-line interfaces with variety of options of different types and actions.
For ex. the allowed network classes names can be supplied through [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices):

```
...
parser = ArgumentParser(description='Ping network addresses by network class')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--nclass', choices=('A', 'B'), required=True, help='Choose class A or B')
```

---

The final optimized implementation:

```
import threading
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from itertools import product
import subprocess


def check_host(host: str):
    return_code = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-q", host],
                                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                 stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).returncode
    print(f'response for pinging {threading.current_thread().name} is {return_code}')

    status = 'up' if return_code == 0 else 'down'
    print(f'{host} : is {status}')


def start_threads(addr_range):
    for addr in addr_range:
        t = threading.Thread(target=check_host, args=(addr,), 
                             name=f'Thread:{addr}')
        t.start()
        yield t


def ping_network_range(net_class: str):
    net_class = net_class.upper()
    if net_class == 'A':
        threads = list(start_threads(f'127.0.0.{i}' for i in range(256)))
    elif net_class == 'B':
        threads = list(start_threads(f'127.0.{i}.{j}' 
                                     for i, j in product(range(256), range(256))))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Wrong network class name {net_class}')

    for t in threads:
        t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Ping network addresses by network class')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--nclass', choices=('A', 'B'), 
                        required=True, help='Choose class A or B')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ping_network_range(args.nclass)
```

Sample usage (with timing, under Unix `time` command):

```
time python3 ping_network_range.py -c B > test.txt

real    2m4,165s
user    2m17,660s
sys     4m35,790s
```

Sample *tail* contents of resulting `test.txt` file:

```
$ tail test.txt
response for pinging Thread:127.0.255.250 is 0
127.0.255.250 : is up
response for pinging Thread:127.0.255.252 is 0
127.0.255.252 : is up
response for pinging Thread:127.0.255.253 is 0
127.0.255.253 : is up
response for pinging Thread:127.0.255.255 is 0
127.0.255.255 : is up
response for pinging Thread:127.0.255.254 is 0
127.0.255.254 : is up
```

Comment: Nice answer, contains a lot that mine doesn't.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

- You should run a linter on your program, you have quite a few PEP 8 issues. A lot are from non-standard whitespace usage, and using `cammelCase` rather than `snake_case`. Conforming to one standard - PEP 8 - allows others to more easily address your code. This is as all code looks the same and so can be easily read.
- At one time `%` formatting was deprecated in the Python docs. Given that f-strings are available in Python now, I would recommend converting to either `str.format` or f-strings to increase readability with modern Python best practices.
- You can change `pingBox` to use a ternary to DRY your code.
- You should be able to see that in `createThread` `tlist` is only going to have 1 item. On creation you're going to start the thread and then wait for it to finish running.

  The problem is that you're `Thread.join`ing before you've started all the other threads. This is simple to fix, you just need to build the threads before joining them.
- You can use `str.lower` to simplify your `rangeSelector` if statements.
- If your range starts at 0, then you don't need to specify 0.
- I think you have a bug, 255 is a valid address. You currently are ignoring it tho. You need to specify 256 in the `range`.
- You can use a generator comprehension to make all the IPs you want, that you need to pass to `create_threads`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
import os


def ping_box(thread_name, host):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + host)
    print(f'Response for pinging {thread_name} is {response}')
    status = 'down' if response else 'up'
    print(f'{host}: is {stetus}')


def create_threads(ips):
    for ip in ips:
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=ping_box,
            kwargs={
                "thread_name": f"Thread:{ip}",
                "host": ip
            }
        )
        thread.start()
        yield thread


def range_selector(ip_range):
    if ip_range.lower() == 'a':
        ips = (
            f'127.0.0.{i}'
            for i in range(256)
        )
    elif ip_range.lower() == 'b':
        ips = (
            f'127.0.{i}.{j}'
            for i in range(256)
            for j in range(256)
        )
    else:
        ips = ()
    for thread in list(create_threads(ips)):
        thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    range_selector(input('Choose range A|B :'))
```

Please note the `list` around `create_threads`. This is to avoid the laziness of generator functions, which is not something we want.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code, but it seems there is an error : ```Exception in thread Thread-2361:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: ping_box() got an unexpected keyword argument 'threadName'```

Comment: @Warok Oh yeah there's an error there. You should be able to figure it out. Note, `threadName` vs. `thread_name`.

Comment: I knew you did it on purpose ;)
Thanks for the help and the improvements

Comment: @Warok Nope, just a small typo. :( No problem, :)